# CustomEvent gets @api property automatically

Tags: lightning-web-components

I work with trailhead unit **Create a Child Component and Interact with It** in **Build a Bear-Tracking App with Lightning Web Components** module.

The `bearTile` component triggers `bearview` event in this way:

```
handleOpenRecordClick() {
    const selectEvent = new CustomEvent('bearview', {
        bubbles: true
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(selectEvent);
}
```

in the class code there is also: `@api bear;`

And the top parent component gets the event having access to the `bear` property in the event object:

```
handleBearView(event) {
    // Navigate to bear record page
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: event.target.bear.Id,
            objectApiName: 'Bear__c',
            actionName: 'view',
        },
    });
}
```

I do not understand how it is possible while not declaring a new `detail` property of the `CustomEvent` instance.

Could any of you guide me on with that subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.target` is the element that dispatched the event. Therefore, anything that's an `@api` on the target can be accessed by any other component that can handle the event (by default, just the parent template). You don't need to specify a `detail` in this case. Note that @track and undecorated properties will not be accessible.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you.